# Fail to start a process as a service? (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Tags: server, java, services

I'm new to this forum and to Ubuntu/Linux in general so forgive me if this question isn't up to the community standards.

I need to start a Discord bot java executable process as a service. To do that I placed the following script inside my bot's user folder-

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /home/djslo/JMusicBot-0.3.8.jar
```

I then gave it permission to execute using

```
chmod a+x djslo.sh
```

After that, I created a service using `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/djslo.service`

and I placed this inside of it-

```
[Unit]
Description=DJ Slo Discord Bot
[Service]
User=djslo
# The configuration file application.properties should be here:

#change this to your workspace
WorkingDirectory=/home/djslo

#path to executable. 
#executable is a bash script which calls jar file
ExecStart=/home/djslo/djslo.sh

SuccessExitStatus=143
TimeoutStopSec=10
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Finally, I start the service and check its status using-

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable djslo.service
sudo systemctl start djslo
sudo systemctl status djslo
```

I'm getting the following error-

```
Process: 3869 ExecStart=/home/djslo/djslo.sh (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
Main PID: 3869 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
CPU: 2ms
```

I've checked, checked, and rechecked the directories but they all check out. Perhaps it's a permission issue with it being in a user folder? I'm not sure. I'm taking a break for a bit but I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas? I appreciate your patience with me and thanks in advance.

*This is the guide I followed
https://dzone.com/articles/run-your-java-application-as-a-service-on-ubuntu*

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to create a unit with `User=djslo` and then use `sudo` in its `ExecStart` script

Comment: That's a great point @steeldriver. I've omitted the sudo from the script.

Answer (score 1):

Solved with a simple solution. I edited the .sh text file and manipulated a few bits, readding them, and reuploaded the .sh file using WinSCP. Voila. It worked. I suspect a hidden character was added using Notepad++ and it was throwing everything off- hence the 203 Exit Code.